# Hover Text over fill area Python plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plot of digital signals. I am trying to shade in certain ‘stages’ of the process that I am recording. I have tried reading through the documentaion and haven’t found a straight forward answer to the following questions.

1)  First and formost: Can you add hovertext to the fill area? When the cursor is over the ‘Green’ area, I want the cursor box to say “Stage 0”. Here is my code for trying to accomplish this:

```
trace_stage0=go.Scatter(
    x = [points['A'][0], points['B'][0]], 
    y = [1,1], 
    mode = 'line', 
    line = dict(width=0.2, color='rgb(0, 190, 0)'), 
    fill = 'tozeroy',
    hoveron = "fills",
    hovertext = "Stage 0",
    showlegend = False)
for i in range(Num_Channels):
    fig.append_trace(trace0[i],i+1,1)
    fig.append_trace(trace_stage0,i+1,1)
```

2)   How can I get rid of the end points of each line? To me, they are distracting from the information I have trying to portray. I have tried mode = ‘none’, but that apparently takes away my ability to control the color of the fill.

3)  Is there a way to adjust the opaqueness of the fill? I would like to make it a little lighter. Thanks

[image: Digital Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'empet' at community.plot.ly, here is the code that ended up working.  Basically, needed to make a seperate plot just for the shaded section.

```
####  Plot ploints for the text   ####
trace_stages=dict(type='scatter',
     x= stages_x,
     y=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
     mode='markers',
     text=['stage 0', 'stage 1', 'stage 2', 'stage 3', 'stage 4', 'stage 5', 
           'stage 6', 'stage 7', 'stage 8','stage 9', 'stage 10'],
     hoverinfo='text',
     marker=dict(size=[0]),
     showlegend = False
   )
####    Plot for the shading   ####
trace_stage0=go.Scatter(
    x = [points['A'][0], points['B'][0]], 
    y = [1,1], 
    mode = 'markers+lines', 
    line = dict(width=0),            #  Setting width = 0 = no lines
    marker=dict(size=[0,0]),         #  Setting size = [0,0] = no dots
    fill = 'tozeroy',
    fillcolor = 'rgba(190,0,0,.15)',  # The '.15' sets opaqueness
    hoverinfo = "none",
    showlegend = False)
```

Makes for some long code, but it works.